# Scatterplot: different colour & annotation for each observation depending on previous untransformed dataset PCA matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I'm implementing a PCA on the following data (provided in code). I choose 2 components which gives me output in the form [x1, y1], [x2, y2], etc.

I then want to plot these two PCs (a) on a plot (as shown below the code) however I want to colour code them according to the letter in the untransformed data (data). i.e. observation [x1, y1] is originally assigned as "A" therefore I want that to be a different colour to those with corresponding "B" and "C" labels. I think a dictionary is appropriate but not sure how to link the original dataset to the new PCA variables.

I also want to annotate these points (from a) with the names in the original set (data), i.e. [x1, y1] would be annotated with "John".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# load packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# load data
data = np.array([["John","A",1,2,1,3,4,6],
    ["Julie","A",3,1,2,2,2,4],
    ["James","B",2,4,1,1,2,5],
    ["Jemma","C",3,5,1,2,3,2],
    ["Jet","B",1,3,2,1,1,3],
    ["Jane","A",2,4,2,1,3,4]])

# feature array & scale
y = data[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
z = scale(y)

# PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=6)
pca.fit(z)

# scree plot
var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
var1 = np.cumsum(np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_, decimals=4)*100)
#print(var1)
#plt.plot(var1)
#plt.show()

# PCA w/ 2 components
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(z)
a = pca.fit_transform(z)

# colour map **HELP**
#colours = {"A":"red", "B":"green", "C":"blue"}

# annotation **HELP**

# scatter plot
plt.scatter(a[:,0],a[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT:

colour problem SOLVED

annotation problem NEED HELP:

```
names = [rows[0] for rows in data]

plt.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], c=point_colours)
plt.annotate(names, (a[:,0], a[:,1]))
```

same problem when coding as:

```
for i in names:
plt.annotate(names, (a[:,0], a[:,1]))
```

although print names outputs the names i want to annotate, it does not show up on the plot. I have tried using both names and str(names) in the annotate parameters but keep getting

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

and then the graph is outputted without labels.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
point_colors = [colours[row[1]] for row in data]
plt.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], c=point_colors)
```

it creates a list with the color of points.

For the annotation:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    xy = (a[:,0][i], a[:,1][i])
    name = data[i][0]
    plt.annotate(name, xy=xy)
```

You should move xy to avoid the overlap of the text with the point.

Comment: brilliant, any idea for the annotation since a dictionary isnt appropriate as each name is unique?

Comment: I think you need a for loop to add annotations to the points.